# SeriesCoefficient returns unevaluated

Tags: algebra

```
    SeriesCoefficient[x^m, {x, 0, p}]
```

This gives back the same thing. I tried Assumptions, FullSimplify etc. I keep getting back the same thing. The answer is clearly KroneckerDelta[p,m]

Comment: it seems to work only when you give it a numerical value for `m`. as in `SeriesCoefficient[x^4,{x,0,p}]` then it gives `Piecewise[{{1, p == 4}}, 0]`

Answer (score 2):

With Assumptions you get

```
SeriesCoefficient[x^m, {x, 0, p},Assumptions -> Element[{p, m}, Integers]]
(* Piecewise[{{1, m == p}}, 0] *)
```

Comment: That is strange, because I tried this also when I looked at it. But It still returned unevaluated.  I tried `Reals` also. which version are you using? I am using 11.2 on windows. ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dr0re.png)

Comment: Thanks to Ulrich. Now it  works.

Comment: My version is 11.0.1/Windows

Comment: may be then it is a bug? Why does it work on 11.0.1 and not on 11.2? May be if confirmed, this should be reported to WRI.

Comment: I also see no evaluation on 11.2; I think it's a bug/regression.